# Form validation to check repetition in string

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to check the entered string in text-box for repetition. i.e. I want to accept only those String which have no repetition and can have all alphabets (CAPS ON & off) + special characters and all digits?
I tried this regexp for checking repetition

```
var pattern = /(\d).*\1/;
```

and as everything is allowed when it comes to range so i did not make any check for the same but it is not working.
Can anyone help me out with something that can make my  Spin. :-)

Example -    vCc@#^k->Valid VbhUiu->Valid  mnkOOp->Invalid fgty^^m->Invalid

Comment: When posting regex question please add an example of input and output,.

Comment: none of the character in the string should be repeated?

Comment: Yes guys, none of the character should repeat, @elclanrs- I will surely keep that in mind. :-)
Example-    2r$%^?   -   Valid
            2ertu    -   Valid
            2r%&&    -   Invalid

Comment: Why do you want this behaviour?

Comment: I am working on an IEEE paper where i want user to enter a password at Sign-up that should not have repetition.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern = /(.).*\1/;
if (pattern.test(str)) {
    alert("No repetition allowed");
} else {
    alert("Looks good!");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Cyzh6/4/)